# Summing results of an function for each element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, sum

I want to make an array, where each element sums up the result of a function"CosineEffect". For example if the "heliostatNumber" is 3, each element in the "Cosine" array should be the sum of three results of funcion"CosineEffect".

But when I print the result out, it seems that they dont add up. Instead each element is the value of just one result, not three results.

```
float Cosine[10];

    for(int i=0;i<11;i++)
    {
        float sum=0;
        for(int j=0; j<heliostatNumber;j++)
        {
            Cosine[i]=sum+CosineEffect(SunRay[i], ReflectedRay[j]);
        }
        cout<<"Cosine Effect = "<<Cosine[i]<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please, specify the language in the title of the question (and in the tags).

Comment: I have corrected them!

Comment: Your loop goes out of bounds of the `Cosine` array.  It writes to `Cosine[10]` when the only valid indices are `Cosine[0]` to `Cosine[9]`.

Comment: @BrunoBelotti: No, please don't.

Comment: Other than the out-of-bounds array access, it isn't clear exactly what you're looking for.  The code adds up 11 (probably should be 10) individual Cosine values.  The `sum` variable is initialized to 0 each time, and on the surface, nothing is wrong with this code.  So after this code, what should the results be?  All the `Cosine` elements added up?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sorry, why not? There were no indication of the language used, I thought it was a good advice. Why am I wrong?

Comment: @Bruno: Tags do not go in titles. Tags go in tags.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, thank you: next time I'll be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going through your code and thinking about the values of each variable at each step.

In particular, look at `sum`.

```
float sum = 0;
for(int j=0; j < heliostatNumber; j++)
{
    sum = sum + CosineEffect(SunRay[i], ReflectedRay[j]);
}

Cosine[i] = sum;
```

Comment: In the question, there's nothing to indicate `Consine[i]` is initialised (though it may be static if it happens to appear outside the function).  If uninitialised, your proposed `Cosine[i] = Cosine[i] + sum;` has *undefined behaviour* because it reads from Cosine[i] before assigning to it.  Adding an initial `Cosine[i] = 0;` pre-loop would fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell the exact problem without rest of your code, but as I can see the problem is in this line

```
Cosine[i]=sum+CosineEffect(SunRay[i], ReflectedRay[j])
```

It should be

```
Cosine[i]+=CosineEffect(SunRay[i], ReflectedRay[j])
```

You don't modify `sum` variable in you code, it is always `0`.

If you need `sum` somewhere else in the code, you should do it like this

```
 sum += CosineEffect(SunRay[i], ReflectedRay[j]);
 Cosine[i] = sum;
```

Also the condition in `for` loop should be `10` not `11`, because you have array of 10 elements.

Comment: No it shouldn't.  OP is explicitly creating a variable to store the `sum` between iterations - you don't know what else he/she wants to do with that variable.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Well from this part of code I can conclude that `sum` is not necessary. However I have updated my answer in case you're right. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Oh i thought when I create an array[10], there are 11 elements.. from 0 to 10. Thanks! Let me fix that first